# Question about corollary 1.4 of Functional Analysis in Brezis book

Tags: functional-analysis

I didn't quite understand the end of demonstration of corollary 1.4. I will state the corollary 1.3 which is used in corollary 1.4.

- Corollary $1.3 .$ For every $x_{0} \in E$ there exists $f_{0} \in E^{\star}$ such that
  $$
  \left\|f_{0}\right\|=\left\|x_{0}\right\| \text { and }\left\langle f_{0}, x_{0}\right\rangle=\left\|x_{0}\right\|^{2}
  $$

The corollary 1.4 says,

- Corollary $1.4 .$ For every $x \in E$ we have
  $$
  \|x\|=\sup _{f \in E^{\star} \atop \|f\|\leq 1}|\langle f, x\rangle|=\max _{f \in E^{\star}\atop \|f\|\leq 1}|\langle f, x\rangle|
  $$
  the proof is stated in this way:

We may always assume that $x \neq 0.$ It is clear that 
$$(A) \, \, \, \sup_{f \in E^{\star} \atop \|f\| \leq 1} |\langle f, x\rangle| \leq\|x\|$$

On the other hand, we know from Corollary 1.3 that there is some $f_{0} \in E^{\star}$ such that $\left\|f_{0}\right\|=\|x\|$ and $\left\langle f_{0}, x\right\rangle=\|x\|^{2} .$ Set $f_{1}=f_{0} /\|x\|,$ so that $\left\|f_{1}\right\|=1$ and $\left\langle f_{1}, x\right\rangle=\|x\|$.

I underestood the choose of $f_0$ and $f_1$ and the consequence, but i didn't see any link with (A) part, and why he could choose this specific $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is that, because of (A), you know that $\|x\|$ is an upper bound for the set of values $S=\{\langle f,x\rangle;\|f\|\le 1\}$. But to prove that $\|x\|$ is actually the supremum you need extra work, supplied by Corollary 1.3. Namely, you prove that the value $\|x\|$ is actually achieved on some $f$ and thus belongs to the set $S$, and the supremum is indeed a maximum.